# Trying to merge two different queries without success

Tags: sql

I've been trying without success to "merge" two queries in order to obtain the last update date of a product with the latest price.

Take a look at this:

I have 2 different tables: products_table and products_prices

In the **products_table** i have all the different products and everytime an attribute is changed, the field last_update_date is changed as well.

If i want to obtain the last update of a product i use this query:

```
select a.item,a.last_update_date from products_table a inner join
(Select item, max(last_update_date) updates from products_table
group by item) b
on a.item=b.item --item is the product_id
and a.last_update_date=b.updates
```

Also, i have the table **products_prices** which contains all the different prices of the products and if i want to obtain the latest price of a product, i use this query (filtering by request_id):

```
select * from products_prices a
where item_code = ''--Product_id
and request_id = (select max(request_id) from products_prices b where a.item_code=b.item_code);
```

The problem is that i dont know how to merge these 2 queries in order to obtain the latest update of the product AND the latest price in the same row

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select first_query.last_update_date, second_query.latest_price -- or whatever name it is
from
(select a.item, a.last_update_date from products_table a inner join
 (Select item, max(last_update_date) updates from products_table
 group by item) b
 on a.item=b.item --item is the product_id
 and a.last_update_date=b.updates) first_query, 
(select * from products_prices a
where item_code = ''--Product_id
and request_id = (select max(request_id) from products_prices b where a.item_code=b.item_code)) second_query
where
first_query.item = second_query.item_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simpler with window functions:

```
select p.item, p.last_update_date, pp.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.item order by p.last_update_date desc) as seqnum
      from products_table p 
     ) p join
     (select pp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pp.item_code order by pp.request_id desc) as seqnum
      from pp p 
     ) pp
     on pp.item_code = p.item
where p.seqnum = 1 and pp.seqnum = 1;
```